# How to use BLoC in deeper levels of the widget tree?

Tags: dart, flutter

In every bloc pattert tutorial and article I see that the BLoC provider is always instantiated at the top of the widget tree.

My question is how can I use a BLoC in a deeper level of the widget tree, for example, to share state between a couple of widgets?

I've tried instantiating the Provider where I need it to keep state but somehow It ended up being called a large number of time because of the widget re-render.

Any ideas of how can I achieve to keep state between a couple of widget deep down the widget tree?

Comment: You can see this question for an example of what I'm talking about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956108/widget-re-render-when-i-focus-on-a-textfield-bloc-pattern

Comment: There's no difference between the bloc being at the root or in the middle of your tree.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Sorry i didn't clarified. There is a difference because I want to keep the state as long as two forms screens are being filled by the user. When the user press "send" I want to process the data in the Bloc and that's it. So when you open again the first form screen, there is a new instance of the bloc